# how pcap header are being set?

Tags: pcap

Context:
I am writing a sniffer to measure the TCP RTT ( round Time Trip ) between SYN-ACK -> ACK .
The idea is to have the time that it takes since SYN-ACK packets to get back with a ACK packet.

Problem:

The problem is that, sometimes I get negative RTT or very bad measurement due to the way I am calculating the RRT.

So,  RTT =  SYN-ACK pcap_timeval   - ACK pcap_interval

Question:

1) How the timestamp are being set on the pcap headers ?
2) Is there a better way to get the RTT measurement?
3) Could it be possible that the kernel has a timing bug when setting the pcap header?
4) I would like to know how exactly this pcap_timeval is being set.  Any idea where to look? or any other ideas?

```
struct pcap_timeval {
 bpf_int32 tv_sec;           /* seconds */
 bpf_int32 tv_usec;          /* microseconds */
 };


struct pcap_sf_pkthdr {
 struct pcap_timeval ts;     /* time stamp */
 bpf_u_int32 caplen;         /* length of portion present */
 bpf_u_int32 len;            /* length this packet (off wire) */   
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> RTT = SYN-ACK pcap_timeval - ACK pcap_interval

(I assume you mean

> RTT = SYN-ACK pcap_timeval - ACK pcap_timeval

here.)

That will normally be negative, as the ACK is a response to the SYN+ACK, and thus should be sent after the SYN+ACK is received.

> 1) How the timestamp are being set on the pcap headers ?

On almost all operating systems (HP-UX is the only exception I know of), it's set by the kernel to its clock value at some point between when the packet is first seen by the host and when it's handed to the capture mechanism libpcap/WinPcap is using.

> 2) Is there a better way to get the RTT measurement?

RTT = ACK pcap_timeval - SYN-ACK pcap_timeval, as that will normally be positive.

> 3) Could it be possible that the kernel has a timing bug when setting the pcap header?

It's possible, but if SYN-ACK pcap_timeval - ACK pcap_timeval is negative, that's definitely *not* an indication that there's a bug - it *should* be negative.

> 4) I would like to know how exactly this pcap_timeval is being set. Any idea where to look?

In your OS kernel's source code if it's a UN*X, or in the WinPcap driver's source code if it's Windows.